# Max-height on img not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to give the max-height property to an image, which works perfectly in all browsers except IE. The image doesn't resize according to the wrapping division's size.
I searched for solution, people said give `height:auto; width:auto`, but this doesn't seem to work.
I am taking the image link dynamically. So I can't be sure what size will the image have.

I have this :

**HTML** :

```
<header>
<div class="logo">
<img src="<?php echo $logo_link; ?>" />
</div>          
</header>
```

**CSS** :

```
header {
height:10%;
}
.logo {
float:left;
}
.logo img{
max-height: 100%;
width:auto;
}
```

Image inside logo division should resize, because header contains .logo division and I have set the header to height:10% and hence it resizes according to window size. Works absolutely great in other browsers but IE.

Any thoughts or workaround?

Comment: PS - if your IE is really old (lte IE9) you also might want to set `header` to `display: block;`.  This will take care of almost all your IE woes:  http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @Deryck Oh right, thank you for the suggestion, that is there in my reset.css :)

Comment: @jprofitt you are right! I by-mistake put '.header' here instead of 'header', I have the exact same in my file as you said, will edit it here now! :)

Comment: Also may want to fix your PHP - stray `)` and extra `?>"`

Comment: @Deryck Oh my god, that was so stupid of me.. I actually have more of php code inside that, I deleted the other part but forgot to delete the extras at the end.

Comment: PS - if our fixes still haven't solved your problem, try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `header { }`.  A floating element doesn't exactly adhere to restrictions like width/height.

Comment: I tried `overflow : hidden;` , though it just hides the extra part of the image, but I wouldn't want it to go hidden because it will be the site's logo.

Comment: Did you set `header { display: block; }` too?

Comment: Yes sir, that comes by default from the reset.css I have.. still no luck.. ill show a picture of what is happening.
Chrome : http://i1188.photobucket.com/albums/z404/shubhamrajdhar/chrome_zpsd1185c5a.png
IE : http://i1188.photobucket.com/albums/z404/shubhamrajdhar/ie_zps0f709ec2.png
I know pictures can't help much, but I am working on localhost, once I live it on a link, ill surely let you know!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44084/discussion-between-deryck-and-shubham-rajdhar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put 100% height on img and width: auto isn't even nessery, but check the wrapping div before that if it does have real height it may be the image height isn't even the 10% height of the div above it (max-height applise only when the original size is bigger then 100% of the wrapping allement

checked it againg the wrappering element of the image doesn't really have fixed height...

```
header {
height:10%;
}
.logo {
float:left;
height: 100%;
}
.logo img{
height: 100%;/height:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, that worked like a charm! Though I added a `width:auto/9;` because images were going stretched in width (thanks to @deryck for that!)
Thank you again! Answer accepted!

Answer (score 3):

IE has a bug with the image height.  Put this in your CSS to fix it:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this didn't help the image in resizing and fitting it in the desired division size considering the image height. :(

Comment: Refer to my last comment above for an extra potential solution.